# How can I concatinate multiple columns of a filtered calculated table for a mesure in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to filter a calculated table by a parameter value (created with new parameter) then concatinate several columns and display the result in a card.

```
Measure = 
    
    VAR FTab = FILTER('Toy','Toy'[ID] = 'ID Slider Parameter'[ID Slider Parameter Value])

    RETURN
    
    DISTINCT( CONCATENATE(FTab[gender] , FTab[region]))
```

The error that I am getting is Cannot "find table 'FTab'"

The 'Table' I am working with is a calculated table. I know how to do it in Power Query but not with DAX.

I want to filter the table with the slider and add the measure to a card. The output would be something like "fEast".

You can find my .pbix file here http://filedropper.com/Rz9fLpyz

Comment: Please share sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Use CONCATENATEX() instead:

```
Measure = 
VAR FTab = 
    FILTER(
        'Toy',
        'Toy'[ID] = [ID Slider Parameter Value]
    )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX(
        FTab,
        [gender] & [region]
    )
```